# Recent Items aren't recent

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I have the Recent Items tab pinned to the Start menu, but I have noticed some odd behavior. When the folder is empty, new items I open get added to the list in alphabetical order, as it should. Once the visible list is full, all new shortcuts are added to the Recent Items folder (C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent), but the visible list now only shows the first 15 shortcuts ***alphabetically***, not the 15 most recent. For example, let's say my visible list of files ranges from AAA.txt to TTT.pdf. If I open WWW.doc, it will not be added to the list. However, if I open MMM.ppt, it will be added, and TTT.pdf will now be removed.

This Recent Items list should display the most recent 15, in alphabetical order, not the first 15 alphabetically of all of the recent files. Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the recent folder and sort the file by last access date...

Comment: Yes, I tried that.